# Pass variables to another module

Tags: javascript

I have a few modules that access common HTML elements. I was thinking of making a module to create variables for each element to avoid constantly accessing the DOM tree but not sure how to do it.

So...

```
var Handles = (function(){
  var $ag= $('.ui.dropdown.age_group');
  // ... more like above
}());

var SomeModule= (function(){
  console.log($ag);  // Can I access $ag here somehow?
}());
```

Comment: One option would be a module to handle global variables that are shared between modules. You can't access variables confined to a functions scope from outside the function, so you'd have to put $ag somewhere else.

Comment: @luke-ramsden Can you please explain in a bit more detail? Perhaps add an answer with some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `ag` global

```js
var ag;
var Handles = (function(){
  ag = 5;
}());

var SomeModule= (function(){
  console.log(ag); 
}());
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but another option is to call `SomeModule` as a function

```js
var Handles = (function() {
  var ag = 6;
  SomeModule(ag);
}());

function SomeModule(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: But aren't global variables bad? That is part of the reason why I am using modules.

Comment: They can be. All in moderation. In that case you can use the second example and pass input to function or use ZohirSalak example.

Answer (score 0):

If you would you can return it as an object from Handles.

```js
var Handles = (function() {
  var $ag = ['Element'];
  return {
    $ag: $ag
  };
}());

var SomeModule = (function() {
  console.log(Handles.$ag);
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an option, but you can doing this with other forms.

```
   var Handles = (function(){
      var $ag= $('.ui.dropdown.age_group');
      // ... more like above
    }());

    var SomeModule= (function(){
      console.log(Handles.$ag);  // Can I access $ag here somehow?
    }());
```

Also can create a other module to share variables!

```
     var shared = (function () {
        var variable1 = 1;
     })();
     var module1 = (function (shared) {})(shared);
```